# Is there a way to make my nametag a different color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yeah, my nametag is white, and I wanted it rainbow.

Comment: By 'nametag', do you mean [nameplates](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/The_Player#Name) or a Name Tag on another mob?

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. Yes, my IGN, like mine in "VoidChaos".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change the color, but it is not possible, without mods, to have more than one color. Use teams:

```
/scoreboard teams add redcolor
/scoreboard teams option redcolor color red
/scoreboard teams join redcolor @p
```

In the last word in the second command, the allowed colors are "black", "dark_blue", "dark_green", "dark_aqua", "dark_red", "dark_purple", "gold", "gray", "dark_gray", "blue", "green", "aqua", "red", "light_purple", "yellow", and "white".